# separating full name with oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to figure out how to turn my "name" field to show as separate "first name" and "last name" fields on my query. Here is my data:

```
set linesize 250

drop table homework1data;

CREATE TABLE homework1data (
  name VARCHAR2(30),

  address VARCHAR2(30),

  location VARCHAR2(30),

  zip VARCHAR2(10)
  );

INSERT INTO Homework1Data(Name, Address, Location, Zip) 
VALUES('Ferguson, Shawn M.', '1940 Fountainview Court', 'Reynoldsburg, Ohio', '43068');

INSERT INTO Homework1Data(Name, Address, Location, Zip) 
VALUES('Phillips, George', '19 Pleasant St.', 'Columbus, OH', '43231');

INSERT INTO Homework1Data(Name, Address, Location, Zip) 
VALUES('Thompson, Mary', '200 E. Main St.', 'Columbus, Oh', '43215');

INSERT INTO Homework1Data(Name, Address, Location, Zip) 
VALUES('Swatson, Robert', '584 Yellowstone Dr.', 'Westerville, OH', '43081');

INSERT INTO Homework1Data(Name, Address, Location, Zip) 
VALUES('Banks, Heather T.', '19 Pleasant St.', 'Columbus, Ohio', '43231');
```

I think I need to use a select statement with LTRIM and RTRIM but unsure of how to do so

**UPDATE:**

I did this to break my fields up:

```
SELECT substr(name, 1, instr(name, ',')) "Last Name",substr(name, instr(name, ' ', 1)) "First Name", address,substr(location, 1, instr(location, ',')) "City",substr(location, instr(location, ' ', 1)) "State", zip 
FROM homework1data
ORDER BY zip, "Last Name" , "First Name";
```

but now my query report has too much space in between each column so that you have to use to scroll bar to see the last field. Is this adjustable? Tried changing line and pagesize but was unsuccessful.

Also, just realized that for some reason all of my rows have duplicated (can be seen in screenshot), giving me doubles of everything. Not sure how or why this happened?

[image: report screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried? You realize this is not a site where you get people to do your homework for you for free, right?

Comment: HINT: `INSTR` will let you find the position of the comma in the string and `SUBSTR` will let you get the everything from the 1st character up until that comma (last name), or from the comma through the end of the string (first name).

Comment: Thanks @MatthewMcPeak, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or a real problem?  In reality, human names are complex.  People have multiple middle names, no middle name, first names with spaces, etc.  Do you have to handle all these?  Or just the sample data you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', 1) AS FirstName,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', -1) AS LastName,
    address,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ',', 1) AS State,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ',', -1) AS City,
    zip
FROM homework1data
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Oracle SQL's you can use such a powerful tool as a regular expression:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (name, '^\w+') as first_name,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR (name, '\w+$') as last_name
FROM
    homework1data
```